# How to make an redirectSSL in the vhost

Tags: apache, ssl

I get slightly crazy :)

I have a domain example.com and I have a SSL certificate for www.example.com
The example.com refers to the IP address of the server (it is an EC2 instance).

In the vhost.conf of the Server I have the following entries

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example-wp
  SSLEngine On
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I took the information from the apache wiki.
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Thanks for helping
Tristan

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. You already have the required directives to perform the redirect to HTTPS. There are other directives that are required of course such as SSLCipherSuite, SSLCertificateFile, and SSLCertificateKeyFile for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the necessary directives listed to perform the redirect. You also need to tell the vhost file where your certificate and key for the certificate exist. You also need to say whether or not a directory the user browses to is to load SSL. Please see a full example configuration file below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com  
  ServerAlias example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@local    

  DocumentRoot /path/to/web/content
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

  ErrorLog logs/error_log
  CustomLog logs/access combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/certfile.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/keyfile.key

  <Directory "/path/to/web/content/">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SSLRequireSSL
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still it doesn't work. The strange thing is that the redirect which should go to www.example.com does not work. Instead it is redirected to https://example.com and consequently I need in the 443 virtual host lines a ServerAlias example.com which I don't want. But i need my site to be online. The users get a message that the certficate does not work but better than to be offline. So why does the redirect to https www.example.com not work?

Comment: You have differing "ServerNames" essentially. You can have ServerName and ServerAlias and both have it redirect to HTTPS. I updated my example to suit your needs. So now if you do www.example.com or example.com it will redirect you to https:// www.example.com

Comment: I have it exactly like this but for whatever reason it is not possible to switch to https www.example.com but only to https example.com and consequently the certificate does not work. No clue what to do.

Comment: solved! The settings in the wordpress were set to example.com and not www.example.com.